# Как получить список аргументов объекта Date?

Tags: дата, javascript

Как получить список аргументов объекта Date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы имеет ввиду [объект Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), то по ссылке вы можете увидеть какие аргументы можно передать в него.

Comment: Спасибо, а если можете, обьясните, пожалуйста, как мне вытащить с него время (именно часы) и засунуть, например, в переменную timeHour? А то я уже два часа не могу раздуплится. )

Comment: @mi4i, почитайте внимательно документацию по ссылке.